# VBA to sum column with particular header and capture in a master file

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have the below code that, when pointed at a particular folder, will capture the following data in my check tab : file name, number of rows, number of columns. The final part i need help with is to find a header, say its "value", and sum the column, posting the total adjacent to each file name starting in cell d8. Code below. Any ideas how to do this easily?

```vb
    Sub CollectData()

    Dim fso As Object, xlFile As Object
    Dim sFolder$
    Dim r&, j&, k&
    
    '*
    Sheets("Check").Activate
    Range("F8:I50").ClearContents
    Range("A8:D50").Copy Range("F8")
    Range("A8:D50").ClearContents
    
    '*
     
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path
        If .Show Then sFolder = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
    End With
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each xlFile In fso.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
        With Workbooks.Open(xlFile.path, Password:="password")
            With .Sheets(1)
                j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                k = .Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                             
                               
            End With
            .Close False
            
        End With
               
        r = r + 1
        Cells(r + 7, 1).Value = xlFile.Name
        Cells(r + 7, 2).Value = j
        Cells(r + 7, 3).Value = k
                
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
       
    Next
         

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just iterate over the header cells and check for cell.value:

```
Dim headers As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim SumRange As Range
Dim Sum As Double

    Set headers = Range("F8:I8")
    
    For Each c In headers
    
        If c.Value = "value" Then
            'From the header, go 1 cell down and get range of continous non blank cells
            'Set the SumRange variable to this range of cells
            Set SumRange = Range(c.Offset(1, 0), c.End(xlDown))
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    'Iterate over the SumRange cells, and add to Sum variable as you go
    For Each c In SumRange

        Sum = Sum + c.Value

    Next
    
    'Display Sum in destination cell
     Cells(r + 7, 4).Value = Sum
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the above. I'm not very clear on this part: For the adding of sum: (Use same logic as you already have, End(xlDown) to set a sum range, and iterate over that range and add to sum as above). I've not been able to get it to sum the column at all. Also how would i integrate it into my original code for the quickest results? Sorry, I'm still a novice with all this

Comment: No problem mate. I have added the rest of the code, some comments and some edits. Hope it helps!

Comment: PS.
**1.** You can add the `Set headers = Range("F8:I8")` line and the two `For Each` statements inside your `With .Sheets(1)` code block. **2.** The Dims (declarations) should be in the top of your original code. **3.** The `Cells(r + 7, 4).Value = Sum` goes with your other resulting statements.